# How to serialize IList<T> field without to generate complex AssemblyQualifiedName?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a project to serialize using WCF DataContractSerialize. 
When serialize the field `public IList<Simple> List2;` in a class, it always generate to

```
<a:List2 z:Id="536" i:type="b:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[SerializationTypes.Simple, Serialization.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9d77cc7ad89668eb]]" z:Size="2" >
  <c:Simple z:Ref="525" i:nil="true"/>
  <c:Simple z:Ref="534" i:nil="true"/>
</a:List2>
```

I don't want the hard code part `Serialization.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9d77cc7ad89668eb` exist in the result, Because I need to take the serialize result as a baseline. Since it is the Assembly Qualified Name of the `genericType` in the field. So I can't find a method to change it.

Could you help to find a method to resolve it?

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Collection2
{
    [DataMember]
    public IList<Simple> List2;
}
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Simple
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Data;
    public Simple() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper class around the list using `CollectionDataContract`:

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class SimpleList: List<Simple> {
    public SimpleList() { }
    public SimpleList(IEnumerable<Simple> simple) : base(simple) { }
}
```

Then modify `Collection2` to use this class instead:

```
[DataMember]
public SimpleList List2;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I have tried this method. This idea is very helpful to me. I will do it on the IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>,  IDictionary<T, T>, IList<T> fields.